# Problem with comparing 2 CStrings that appear identical

Tags: c++, c-strings

2 strings which appear to be equal, don't test as equal. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. I have added a watch for each CString, and in the watch window they appear identical. But when i try to compare them using:
a = b;
or a.compare(b);

they don't compare.

```
bool CDictionaryClass::CheckWord(CString word)
{
    // get starting position for search
    LPTSTR buff = word.GetBuffer(10);

    wchar_t testChar = tolower(buff[0]);
    int loc = int(testChar) - 97;
    int end,testLength,test;
    CString testWord = word.MakeLower(),dictWord;

    testLength = word.GetLength();
    word.ReleaseBuffer();

    if(loc == 25)
        end = GetNumberOfWords();
    else
        end = ABCPositions[loc+1];

    for(int i=ABCPositions[loc]; i<end; i++)
        if(dictionaryWords[i].length == testLength)
            {
            dictWord = dictionaryWords[i].word.MakeLower();
            if(testWord == dictWord)
                return true;
            }

    return false;
}
```

I expect testWord to equal dictWord

Comment: If you have a real c-string, you should compare the content and not the address. But I have no idea if CString is a c-string with an compare operator or not.

Comment: *and in the watch window they appear identical.* -- That is because the "watch window" does not show (or is not easy to show) control characters, invisible characters, etc.  Either use the "Memory Window", where you see the actual byte/hex values of the characters, or simply write a loop to show the characters that make up each string to show what the actual characters that are making up the string.  But seriously, these are the things you should have investigated before posting -- the program is not telling a lie -- the strings are not the same.